# How bad does MAR have to get to be inevitably of concern?

Tags: logistic, missing-data, data-imputation

The textbook literature says that multiple imputation is valid if data is MCAR or MAR.
MAR means that the probability of missingness is dependent of observed information, but not unobserved information. If i consider the variables the missingness depends on, my imputations are valid and unbiased ([2] p.8).

A widely used test for MCAR vs. MAR is running logistic regression and identification of significant predictors [1](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/missing-data-evaluation.html). Problem: The larger the number of observations, the higher the probability that parameters become significant as standard errors decrease with larger n.

What bothers me is, how small or large does a MAR-Variable-Coefficient have to be to really make a difference in the imputation model?

Here is an example. Same influence of V4 and V5, different n.

```
rm(list=ls())
tdf <- function(nobs){
  set.seed(666)
  # generate some data
  dat <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = nobs, 
                       mu = c(1500, 100, 100, 100, 100), 
                       Sigma = matrix(data = c(1.0, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1,
                                               0.9, 1.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
                                               0.1, 0.1, 1.0, 0.1, 0.1,
                                               0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0, 0.1,
                                               0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0), 
                                      nrow = 5, byrow = T))
  dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
  # target variable is V1, MAR means missingness of V1 depends on V2 and V3
  dat$mis <- 1000+ 10*dat$V2 + 5*dat$V3 + 1*dat$V4 + .5*dat$V5
  range01 <- function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
  dat$mis <- range01(dat$mis)
  dat$e <- rbinom(nrow(dat), 1, .5)
  dat$V1[dat$mis > .5 & dat$e] <- NA
  
  dat$ismi <- (is.na(dat$V1))
  mod <- glm(ismi~V2+V3+V4+V5, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = dat)
  print(summary(mod))
}
tdf(1000)
tdf(10000)
```

If i would leave V4 and V5 out at a nobs of 1000 (p > .05), would it make my imputations invalid, as formally V4 and V5 are not independent if missingness?

As the influence is small, i would guess not.

Van Buuren says in [2] p.168 that

> In addition, include the variables that are related to the nonresponse.
> Factors that are known to have influenced the occurrence of missing data
> (stratification, reasons for nonresponse) are to be included on substan-
> tive grounds. Other variables of interest are those for which the distri-
> butions differ between the response and nonresponse groups. These can
> be found by inspecting their correlations with the response indicator of
> the variable to be imputed. If the magnitude of this correlation exceeds
> a certain level, then the variable should be included.

This "certain threshold" is to be determined by the analyst, i guess?

Lets say i have some hypotheses about the missingness mechanism, and the variables i assume  show a really low but significant influence, while i have variables with high significant influence with no theoretical explanation. Would it be okay then to leave out my theoretically "important" variables as they are numerically not that important and fall under my defined threshold?

[2]: Van Buuren (2019) Flexible Imputation of missing data. CRC Press. Available at https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/

Comment: Maybe the abbreviations MAR and MCAR are not general enough that you can use them without explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, alas i do not think that if someone does not know what MAR means in this specific context, he wont be able to answer my question anyways. It is like having to explain the term "water" when asking a question on how much arsenic is needed to poison a water reservoir to the level of being harmful to humans after consumption.

Comment: @spssstataR-guy not everyone is here to answer questions, and instead one may also learn from questions (provided that it is a clear question). It is also exaggerated to compare terms like MAR and MCAR with water. On this forum the term water occurs about 4 times more often than MCAR. In addition you do not need to explain MAR and MCAR but at least spell out the abbreviation once (and a link to some background would be nice as well). And who knows, maybe there is an arsenic-expert here that could answer your question if they would know what water means.

Comment: *"And who knows, maybe there is an arsenic-expert here that could answer your question if they would know what water means"* For example, from my own experience, I am not an expert but that makes my answers sometimes nice/good because it is written from the perspective of a non-expert. I am not being hindered by expertise when I need to explain simple textbook questions.

Comment: I really did not intend to cause a discussion on the formulation of questions or the intentions of visiting users on stackexchange. Maybe you got a point here, maybe not. I did not compare MAR or the like with water, i just used it as an analogy. It could have been anything. If i would ask if "pulling teeth" (low MAR mechanism) ruined metallicas kill em all (multiple imputation in general), i do not want an answer of anyone not knowing who metallica (MI) is, lest knows the album/song (mechanism), and is not able to google the terms if he wants to help without knowledge.

Comment: I have been thinking some more about your problem, but could not really get to an answer yet. I had some more issues. **1** Your covariance matrix is not symmetric (I have not computed your code, does it give an error or can you just use an asymmetric covariance matrix?) **2** It seems like you are not looking at a difference between mar and mcar but instead between mar and mnar. Your data is mar, and the missing of values depends on the other variables, but when you exclude those other values than it becomes mnar.

Comment: 1) this is true, i corrected this. 2) this is my question. how large does MAR have to get to be of concern (so it counts as no longer valid assumption and turns into MNAR if variables are left out of imputation procedure)? if sample size is sufficiently large, i will get a plethora of "MAR-Variables" (see, e.g. gwern.net/Everything)